# Set run parameters?

Tags: android, runtime, dalvik

how would I go about and set runtime parameters on Android to be used with dalvik?
For example, I would set the runtime parameter I need with -Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols=TLSv1 on a system using the "regular" JVM like Windows.
How would I do the same for my Android app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. You have no control over such runtime parameters for ordinary Android apps, even to the extent that such things are used by the Dalvik virtual machine.

Libraries that need such parameters (versus also having an API for passing in the values) may need to be modified to be Android compatible.